# Recursive Query ordering by find order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I am building a query, in which i need the results to be returned in the order that the query found the values.

HERE IS THE QUERY

```
DECLARE @Query TABLE
(
    [ParentID] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [ChildID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Action] VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
);

WITH q
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT M1.[ParentID], M1.[ChildID], M1.[Action]
    FROM [dbo].[xNodes] M1
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[xNodes] M2 ON M1.[ParentID] = M2.[ChildID]
    WHERE M1.[ChildID] = 'PCMN014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT M.[ParentID], M.[ChildID], M.[Action]
    FROM q
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[xNodes] M ON q.[ParentID] = M.[ChildID]
)
INSERT INTO @Query ([ParentID], [ChildID], [Action])
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM q;

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @Query

SELECT * FROM @Query q WHERE [ParentID] IS NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM @Query q WHERE [ParentID] = 'IDS' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM @Query q WHERE [ParentID] = 'EFL' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM @Query q WHERE [ParentID] = 'PEFL001' UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM @Query q WHERE [ParentID] = 'PCMN010'
```

The ugly union all at the end shows the order that i want them in. The following table represents what I get from my query.

```
***ParentID, ChildID, Action***
NULL,       IDS,        Launch IDS
EFL,        PEFL001,    [Click] Case Management > Case Review Workbasket
IDS,        EFL,        Log into IDS
PCMN010,    PCMN014,    [Click] Title Search arrow beside Title
PEFL001,    PCMN010,    [Click] User Search arrow beside User ID
PEFL001,    PCMN010,    [Click] User Search arrow under File Location - Person
```

The following is what i expect. Notice the 2nd row's ParentID is the ChildID of the first row, and so on.

```
***ParentID, ChildID, Action***
NULL,       IDS,        Launch IDS
IDS,        EFL,        Log into IDS
EFL,        PEFL001,    [Click] Case Management > Case Review Workbasket
PEFL001,    PCMN010,    [Click] User Search arrow beside User ID
PEFL001,    PCMN010,    [Click] User Search arrow under File Location - Person
PCMN010,    PCMN014,    [Click] Title Search arrow beside Title
```

Comment: Why can't your final select simply accept all ParentID, then order by parentsID with a case statment to precedence. This would eliminate the unions and give control on ordering.

Comment: that would group them yes together yes, but it will mess with expected order since ordering by ParentID is alphabetical

Comment: I think you want it in reverse, as you are starting from the child node. check my answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean a regular "Order by ParentID" but rather Order by Case when Parentid = 1 then 2, when parentid = 2 then 1 etc..." allowing a completely custom sort

Comment: Ive come to to the conclusion that i need to build this solution in c# then present the list . thank all

Comment: I dont think this is the domain of C#, anyhow if you add more info to your question people here can help, add your input dataset that is giving you trouble, one or more, and give more info about your custom sort, and expected output for each. if "Case" helps use it in order by ". As for the data provided my answer ordered it as per the order that you presented.

Answer (score 0):

Lets add a Seq column that will help get the order you want.

```
DECLARE @Query TABLE
(
    [ParentID] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [ChildID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Action] VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,
    [Seq] int
);

WITH q
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT M1.[ParentID], M1.[ChildID], M1.[Action],1 [Seq]
    FROM [dbo].[xNodes] M1
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[xNodes] M2 ON M1.[ParentID] = M2.[ChildID]
    WHERE M1.[ChildID] = 'PCMN014'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT M.[ParentID], M.[ChildID], M.[Action],q.[Seq]+1 [Seq]
    FROM q
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[xNodes] M ON q.[ParentID] = M.[ChildID]
)
INSERT INTO @Query ([ParentID], [ChildID], [Action],[Seq])
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM q 

SELECT [ParentID], [ChildID], [Action] FROM @Query order by [Seq] desc
```

The output will be:-

```
ParentID    ChildID            Action
========    =======            =====
NULL        IDS                Launch IDS
IDS         EFL                Log into IDS
EFL         PEFL001            [Click] Case Management > Case Review Workbasket
PEFL001     PCMN010            [Click] User Search arrow beside User ID
PEFL001     PCMN010            [Click] User Search arrow under File Location - Person
PCMN010     PCMN014            [Click] Title Search arrow beside Title
```

Comment: Sorry but i have considered that. The issue is that the order can be as follows.

1, 2, 5, 3
but it can also be 
5, 4, 3

Since 3 can be a child of 4 and 5, there is is no logical sequence order num to assign.